# Nested Objects with a different <a href>?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there any way to give a nested object a different hyperlink?

I don't think  tags can be nested but is there anyway to have the img's associated with a href in some fiendish way?

So here for example

```
 <a href="blahblah.php">
 <object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="svgimage.svg" >
 <img src="pngimage.png" type="image/png" />
 </object>
  </a>
```

if the svg can't be loaded the png comes and the user can click and go to a separate set of pages. blobblob.php

WHY? well in the pages that follow (aimed at mobile) constantly serving back-up png to svg mobile devices is a waste. So for android pre 3.0 i want to serve them separate png files.

JAVASCRIPT? Ideally not.

Comment: I had this problem before. Solved with jQuery.

Comment: I can fully imagine that there will not be a solution....

Comment: Let me know if you want jquery

Comment: Put it up (it'll be best feasible workaround probably) and I'll upvote it but not accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use image maps.

```
<a href="blahblah.php">
    <object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="svgimage.svg" >
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" type="image/png" usemap="#mapping"/>
    </object>
</a>
<map name="mapping">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="bloblob.php" />
</map>
```

This works the way you intended.

As also shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xr3gT/

Comment: Thanks this works. Very clever and fiendish! Android has js support generally but what with users disabling, and that this works in IE 8 I'm happy! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('object').click(function () {
    window.location.href = 'whatever url you want';
    return false;
 });
```

OR

```
 $('object').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'whatever url you want';
 });
```

Both should work

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There is some javascript, but not much. No jQuery or any other library necessary.

```
<a href="blahblah.php">
    <object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="svgimage.svg" onclick="return false; window.location.href='http://example.com'" >
        <img src="pngimage.png" type="image/png" onclick="window.location.href='http://example.com/differentlocation'; return false;" />
    </object>
</a>
```